# Mysql Full text search in PHP returning multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search

Hi stackoverflow community,
I'm having a problem with Mysql full text search in PHP. The code below is working, however, it is returning multiple articles for each individual matching keyword. I want to return a distinct article for each keyword and order them by relevance.

**Screen shot for the code below**

[image]

code

```
      function relatedArticle($item, $category){
          global $con;

        $keywords=removePrepositions($item);

        $keyword_tokens = explode(' ', $keywords);

           $x=0;
           $query_result='';
        foreach($keyword_tokens as $item) {

            $x++; 
            $construct = " "; 
            $construct=$item;

         $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM apps WHERE Match(title) AGAINST ('$construct' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and Type = '$category' LIMIT 4";

       $query_result=$con->query($query) or trigger_error($con->error."[$query]");

        echo"<div id='Big_container_rel'>"; 
          echo"<div id='container_rel'>";   
        while($row=$query_result->fetch_array()){

             echo"<div id='container1_rel'>";

             $AdTitle=pre_replace($row['title']);
             $type= strtolower(pre_replace($row['Type']));

             echo"<a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'><img id='imgMobi' alt=".$row['title']." src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/></a>";
             echo"<br/><h4><a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'>".$row['title']."</a></h4>";

            echo"</div>";


            }
            echo"</div>";
         echo"</div>";

        }               

      }
```

Please help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed solving the problem

```
function relatedArticle($item, $category){
              global $con;

            $keywords=removePrepositions($item);

            $keyword_tokens = explode(' ', $keywords);

               $query_result=implode(',', $keyword_tokens);
               $construct='';

             $construct=$query_result;
             $query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM apps WHERE Match(title) AGAINST ('$construct' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) and Type = '$category' limit 4";

           $query_result=$con->query($query) or trigger_error($con->error."[$query]");

            echo"<div id='Big_container_rel'>"; 
              echo"<div id='container_rel'>";   
            while($row=$query_result->fetch_array()){

                 echo"<div id='container1_rel'>";

                 $AdTitle=pre_replace($row['title']);
                 $type= strtolower(pre_replace($row['Type']));

                 echo"<a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'><img id='imgMobi' alt=".$row['title']." src='uploads/".$row['image']."'/></a>";
                 echo"<br/><h4><a href='/".$type."/".$row['appId']."/".$AdTitle."/'>".$row['title']."</a></h4>";

                echo"</div>";


                }
                echo"</div>";
             echo"</div>";



          }
```

What is prouding screen shot

[image]

Comment: what did you solve?what was the problem in this script?

Comment: I have re-edited the answer. Commpare those two screen shots. It is returning one article regardless of how many times the article keyword is found in every keyword for the full text search. I have removed the foreach which is creating a loop and worked perfectly.

Comment: Every row represents each keyword found in the first screen shot . I hope have answered you